# saveas dialogue in Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I found many of the answers in these forums very useful for me but would request you to check this issue of mine.

I'm trying to save a `.csv` file from a servlet that is called by a jquery method. Though I'm setting the header and the `content-diposition`. I'm not getting the dialogue box in the browser after stream writing the data.

```
function popup(data) {
    $.post("cisco-fetch-devices", { orderId : data},
        function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);  
        });
    });
}
```

The above jquery code is calling the below servlet post method:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"tableincsv.csv\"");
    java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("test data");
}
```

After the data is sent back to the browser, the dialogue box is not displayed. However the data that is set in the servlet `out.print` is displayed correctly displayed in the `alert` message of the JS method.

Please give me your inputs on this.

Thanks,
aditya

Comment: Should I add anything in the success method for the 'save as' dialog box to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : you can't do it with AJAX, which ignores Content-Disposition header in order to be able to feed its data object. You have to rely on the browser, which honours this header.

So, **do a regular POST** (with hidden fields) **or GET** (with querystring parameters) on your servlet.

Or use [this jQuery Plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/), recommended by user [Vinodh Ramasubramania on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery), to automate the process. Code is very short and does just that...

There are numerous threads on this topic :

- here

  - [How does jQuery.post() deal with Content-Disposition: attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824630/content-disposition-does-not-cause-a-save-as)
  - [POST to server, receive PDF, deliver to user w/ jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery)
  - …
- and on forum.jquery.com :

  - [jQuery.post returning binary content](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-jquery-post-returning-binary-content)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! But can you please help on one more issue?-  I'm not able to call the servlet Post method from the dynamically generated form tag:

Comment: Here is the link to that question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948016/not-able-to-call-servlet-dopost-method-from-js-form