# Not able to call servlet doPost method from JS form

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I'm facing an issue in calling a servlet doPost method from my dynamically generated Javascript form.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");

    form.setAttribute("action", 'cisco-fetch-devices');
    form.setAttribute("method", 'POST');

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", 'hiddeninputfield');
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", data);

    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
```

However I'm able to call the same servlet ''cisco-fetch-devices' from a jquery ajax call:

```
    $.post("cisco-fetch-devices", { orderId : data},
    function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
```

The JS dynamic form submit is generating a 'File not found error'

Here is my doPost method:

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {



            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"tableincsv.csv\"");

             String orderId = request.getParameter("orderId").toString();
             java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             out.print("TEST DAta");


        }
```

Could you please let me know what might be the issue in the traditional POST call of JS?

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: I'm not sure may be yes. But it has been a long time since I posted here. I did get couple of quick answers today including yours.

Comment: You can go back and check your questions and see if they've been answers--it's never too late to accept an answer, as long as it actually answers the question.

Comment: _The JS dynamic form submit is generating a 'File not found error'_ : Can you provide with more detail? Like URL and detailed message if any (sounds like a 404 error, but maybe you would have noticed ;-))

Answer (score 1):

The data you're sending won't be the same--your `hiddeninputfield` field should be named `orderId`, and be initialized with the order ID. Alternatively, you could parse the `hiddeninputfield` request parameter, but that seems kind of silly.

The jQuery call correctly sends an `orderId` form value.

It would have been very simple to debug this by seeing that `orderId` was `null` in the servlet, and/or by looking at the actual request sent by the browser to see what parameters were being sent, and how.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Have modified the code. But the error still persists 'Http 500 internal server error' the page is not found. Any inputs?

Comment: @AdityaR You need to debug. Make sure the request is the same. See what's happening in `doPost`. The normal debug process--I can't see your server's logs, so I have no idea what's causing the 500 response.